# React Router V4 - route with params failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

With react router v4 i'm failing to create a route with params:

```
const Parent = () => 
 <Main>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/places" component={PlacesView} />
      <Route path="/places/:placeId" component={PlacesDetailView} />           
      <Route path="/callback" component={CallbackView }/>
    </Switch>    
 </Main>

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
         <div>
           <Route path='/' component={Parent} />
         </div>
      </Router>
);}
```

Everything that comes after /places simply fails to render the app.

Even if I add an extra subroute like /places/detail, it fails to render the app.

Edit: The Main component renders a navigation bar and the child components:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <Progress />
   <Navigation location={this.props.location}/>
   <div id="page-wrapper" className={wrapperClass}>
       <TopHeader />
       {this.props.children}
       <Footer />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 404? when I copy your code and go to `/places/foo` I get linked to `PlacesView` because Switch will return the first matching path

Comment: you need to use `exact` to ensure that your more general route isn't hit

Comment: @azium `/places/foo` returns me 404

Comment: @HunterMcMillen tried that same outcome.

Comment: @joaofs Can you link the entirely of your setup? The issue could be elsewhere.

Comment: what happens when you visit route `/places` does it work

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri every route works except any subroute like `/places/foo` or anyother subroute on any route.

Comment: I don't understand how you can get 404. React router doesn't come with a premade 404 page. are you getting 404 from trying to load a resource?

Comment: @azium you right, 404 is the bundle failing to load on the `/places/` route. It actually fails to render the app. Just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced exactly the same issue as OP. [This tutorial](http://jpsierens.com/tutorial-react-redux-webpack/) helped me find the solution.

Adding the following lines into webpack.conf.js resolved the issue.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    ...
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
```